# Read table in pandas with lowercase column using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, pandas, oracle, sqlalchemy

I would like to read a table in my database as pandas dataframe. I am working with `sqlalchemy` and it seems to me that it only executes queries in uppercase.

The table XYZ in my schema has a column name "pred_pred" in lowercase. When I do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle as ora
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine import url

connect_url = url.URL(...)
engine = create_engine(connect_url)
connection = engine.connect()

input = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT pred_pred FROM XYZ', connection)
```

I get the following error:

```
DatabaseError: ORA-00904: "PRED_PRED": invalid identifier
```

Is there a workaround?

---

EDIT: as a workaround at the moment I am simply importing all columns using `*` and then working on them in `pandas` because the table has only few columns. I would still like to know if it's possible to solve this problem in a more direct way.

Comment: Unquoted identifiers are case insensitive in SQL, and Oracle converts unquoted identifiers to upper case, if I remember correctly (for example Postgres does the exact opposite). If your column is in lower case, perhaps you must use a quoted identifier: `"pred_pred"`,

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you mean to use ```query = 'SELECT '+"pred_pred"+' FROM XYZ'``` ? I get the same error message.

Comment: No he means `query = 'SELECT "pred_pred" FROM XYZ'` directly. Btw, never use such a string concatenation, because of vulnerability to injection.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan hear hear :D:D

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan There's a time for everything, and *she's* grown quite a bit, so a new photo is in order, I guess :D

Comment: oooh a daughter, should be better to have a daughter :) @IljaEverilä, I'm sure she's becoming cuter as started to talk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As also described in comment, you should just add double quotes to wrap your `columns` as oracle converts it to upper case if it is not wrapped with double quotes.

I think you need something like following:

```
input = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT "pred_pred" FROM XYZ', connection)
```

Because you must have created the `xyz` table with `column` wrapped in double quotes, it is stored as case sensitive name i.e lowercase.

See this [db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=70595de5ba095903a8d06388722bbf96) for more clarification.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

It depends how the table was created in the first place. By default, it doesn't matter if the DDL for that table was written in uppercase or lowercase, Oracle will change it all to uppercase and store it in the database.

That means, that bellow DDL statements are equal for Oracle:

```
create table table1 (column1 VARCHAR2(20));
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (COLUMN1 VARCHAR2(20));
```

Table with such creation DDL can be simply queried both by:

```
SELECT COLUMN1 FROM TABLE1;
SELECT column1 FROM table1;
```

However, different issue is, when the table name or column is specified with double quotes.

```
create table table1 ("column1" VARCHAR2(20));
```

Then everytime you're querying that column, it has to be always queried again by those quotes and with the exact casing as it was created:

```
SELECT "column1" FROM TABLE1;
```

Regarding to Python code, in REPL it seems that you can easily combine double quotes with single quotes:

```
>>>input = 'SELECT "pred_pred" FROM XYZ'
>>>input
>>>'SELECT "pred_pred" FROM XYZ'
```

So the correct code you can just change your code with:

```
input = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT "pred_pred" FROM XYZ', connection)
```

To be sure that we're approaching the correct issue in here, you might want to connect to your database via for example SQL developer and query:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE UPPER(TABLE_NAME) = 'XYZ'
```

If the column_name is not all upperacase, then it was created with double quotes and must be therefore queried the same way.
Further reading regarding to naming rules https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223

You already mentioned the workaround with * in the comments - but it seems to be bad idea to query with * and do the projecting part on the Python side, since it would be raising the needed IO operations on the database side.